# How to obtain working template from CloudFormation Management Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, deployment, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am working to extend this solution https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome to my needs.

I am using serverless (on my laptop with Debian 9) to deploy it to AWS Lambda. I would like to use AWS-Sam-local https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local to run it locally for developing.

I would like to use AWS-Sam-local because I believe that there is difference between running this solution via `serverless webpack serve --function run` and `sam local start-api`. The difference I think, is `event` object which I want to make contain POST or binary data (multipart files transfer). For that I have to allow binary transfer via API Gateway.
But correct me if I am wrong because I am totally green in the AWS and Serverless field and this is my first time with this technologies.

The problem I get is `aws-sam-local` needs the `CloudFormation` **template** to know how to run `serverless-chrome` project. If I make deploy to AWS and go to CloudFormation Console I can copy that template after selecting it in "Stacks" table and clicking "Template" tab. Then I use `cfn-flip` to convert JSON into YAML. In the end I got template.yml, but running `sam local start-api` gives me error:

```
2017/10/06 11:03:23 Connected to Docker 1.32
ERROR: No Serverless functions were found in your SAM template.
```

Please tell me what to do to make `serverless-chrome` run locally as it would run on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates Serverless uses to deploy are available in two places:

- Remotely, in the S3 deployment bucket
- locally, in `.serverless/`

Comment: That is what I also tried from `.serverless/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json template.yml` but got the same error `ERROR: No Serverless functions were found in your SAM template.` :(

Comment: I don't think the cloud formation stacks are compatible. If you're already using Serverless, why not use serverless-offline plugin?

Comment: I didn't know it exists, I'll go check that plugin.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `serverless-offline` plugin, in the beginning I just overthought all off that. Best regards!